# Facebook Logout Option in android

Tags: android, facebook

I am using a *Logout* button in my Activity. When I click this button, I am getting the following response in my DDMS Logcat for the *Logout* method which is in the Facebook Activity.

```
09-12 11:28:59.619: I/Logout(848): {"error_code":101,"error_msg":"Invalid application ID.","request_args":[{"key":"method","value":"auth.expireSession"},{"key":"format","value":"json"}]}
```

But when I run the application again, it asks me to *Login*. Does it mean it had successfully logged out?

Comment: Can you post the code for the "Logout" function?

Comment: public String logout(Context context)
            throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
        Util.clearCookies(context);
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putString("method", "auth.expireSession");
        String response = request(b);
        setAccessToken(null);
        setAccessExpires(0);
        return response;
    }

Comment: The Facebook SDK already has a `LoginButton.java` class with the _Login_ and _Logout_ methods included in the _Hackbook_ example. Why not use that directly? You can see the example here: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/tree/master/examples/Hackbook